# I can not run api-functional test in Magento 2

Tags: phpunit, magento2

I have a problem with running tests during the call:

```
php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit.xml dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Api/AttributeSetManagementTest.php
```

Returns an error:
*Could not read "dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit.xml*

Someone may have a similar problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Magento Dev Docs (Link below).

**Could not read “dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml”**

> This error happens if the integration tests are executed from a different directory than dev/tests/integration. To fix the issue, change into the dev/tests/integration directory and run the tests from there with any relative paths adjusted accordingly.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/test/integration/integration_test_execution.html

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct so that it may help future users. :)